# Two Different Search Functions

Tags: yii

I have two search functions. One for public and one for admin search. They are exactly the same:

```
public function search()
{
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        //$criteria->compare('ID',$this->ID);
        $criteria->compare('t.IDkorisnik',Yii::app()->user->getId());
        $criteria->compare('start_time',$this->start_time,true);
        $criteria->compare('end_time',$this->end_time,true);
        //$criteria->compare('information',$this->information,true);
        $criteria->compare('country',$this->country,true);
        $criteria->compare('city',$this->city,true);
        $criteria->compare('start_price',$this->start_price);
        $criteria->compare('min_bid',$this->min_bid);
        $criteria->compare('valuta',$this->valuta,true);
        $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);

        $criteria->with=array('relationIDuzgajivac','relationIDgolub');
        $criteria->compare('username',$this->uzgajivacSearch);
        $criteria->compare('brojgoluba',$this->golub_search, true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>50),
        ));
}
```

except in search() I have this

```
$criteria->compare('t.IDkorisnik',Yii::app()->user->getId());
```

in publichsearch() I don't.

As you may see there is relation search. when I open admin page it works in publicsearch page it doesn't work, I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I never realized that when I'm creating new action

```
public function actionPublicSearch()
{

    $model=new Auction('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Auction']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Auction'];

    $this->render('publicsearch',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

this `$model=new Auction('search');` within model always has to be 'search' not something like 'public_search'

and then within view, where CGridView is created

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'auction-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->public_search(),
```

dataProvider is a place where I put my search function, in this case public_search